# How to pretty print a json.loads method in Python

Tags: python, json, pretty-print

I am currently having a problem with pretty printing in Python when converting a dictionary from JSON to Python by using `.loads()`. When converting from Python to JSON, I use `indent` as a parameter. However, `.loads()` does not have an indent parameter.

I have looked through the python JSON documentation and they only show how to pretty print using `.dumps()`.

Here is my code to illustrate my point:

```
import json

class Kid:

    def __init__(self, name, age, nickname, isFriendly):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.isFriendly = isFriendly

boy = Kid("Jimmy", 10, None, False)

def encode_kid(o):
    if isinstance(o, Kid):
        return {"name": o.name, "age": o.age,
                "nickname": o.nickname, "Is friendly": o.isFriendly}

boyJSON = json.dumps(boy, default=encode_kid, indent=2)
boyPYTHON = json.dumps(boyJSON, indent=2)

print(boyJSON)
print(boyPYTHON)
```

Comment: have you tried using pprint? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Comment: Just adding on to a comment @sagar1025 made. You can use the `pprint` method found within the `pprint` module to format your JSON output. So when importing try: `from pprint import pprint`. So that you can reference this method instead of your `print()` statement, like so: `pprint(#json)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there might be some confusion on what exactly is going on with the `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` methods.

```
# Serializing boy object to a str named boyJSON 
# -> resulting str will have JSON format 
boyJSON = json.dumps(boy, default=encode_kid, indent=2) 

# Serializing boyJSON str to another str boyPYTHON 
# -> resulting str will have JSON format, now with str literals
boyPYTHON = json.dumps(boyJSON, indent=2)
```

That is why `boyJSON` and `boyPYTHON` will print very differently. If you want them to print the **exact same**, *i.e. "pretty"*, try this:

```
boyJSON = json.dumps(boy, default=encode_kid, indent=2)
boyPYTHON = json.loads(boyJSON) # Converts boyJSON str to a dict

print(boyJSON)
print(json.dumps(boyPYTHON, indent=2)) # Print boyPYTHON dict converted to a str with JSON format
```

Output:

```
>>> print(boyJSON)
{
  "name": "Jimmy",
  "age": 10,
  "nickname": null,
  "Is friendly": false
}    

>>> print(json.dumps(boyPYTHON, indent=2))
{
  "name": "Jimmy",
  "age": 10,
  "nickname": null,
  "Is friendly": false
}

>>> print(boyPYTHON)
{'name': 'Jimmy', 'age': 10, 'nickname': None, 'Is friendly': False}

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(boyPYTHON, width=1)
{'Is friendly': False,
 'age': 10,
 'name': 'Jimmy',
 'nickname': None}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond to my question! However, there is a problem with your answer. When pretty printing using pprint(), I wanted the output to be in python format. Your output for boyPYTHON when pretty printed is still in JSON format.

Comment: Well now I'm confused... What exactly are you asking? Your original question never mentions `pprint()`.

Comment: You are right, I never used pretty print, however, while print(json.dumps(boyPYTHON, indent=2)) nicely formats the code, it is still in JSON format. For example, "nickname" = null (instead of None); "Is Friendly" = false (instead of False). Sorry if I did not clarify myself.

Comment: Ah I now understand. Just updated the last lines of my answer to use `pprint()` for showing `False` and `None` -- was this what you were hoping for?